# Django rest - how to serialise a prefetch related set?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

im trying to load a related set into a serialiser, so the entires would appear as a nested dictionary under the parent.

I currently don't have any errors but my api also is not returning any data at all for circuits_subnets.

any ideas? 
Thanks

**EDIT**

I have added a nested serialiser however the api is still showing no errors and no data

views.py:

```
class DeviceConnViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    # sub queries    
    poll_ip = Subquery(
        DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(device_id=OuterRef(
            'id'),subnet__subnet_type__poll=True).values('subnet__subnet')[:1])
    mgmt_ip = Subquery(
        DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.filter(device_id=OuterRef(
            'id'),subnet__subnet_type__mgmt=True).values('subnet__subnet')[:1])   
    queryset = Device.objects.all().annotate(
                                    poll_ip=poll_ip,
                                    mgmt_ip=mgmt_ip
                                ) \
                                .select_related('site','site__site_type','model','model__device_type') \
                                .prefetch_related('devicecircuitsubnets_set') \
                                .order_by('site__location')  

    serializer_class = DeviceConn
```

serializers.py

```
class CircuitSubnetsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    circuit_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='circuit.name',
    )
    subnet = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='subnet.subnet',
    )
    subnet_mask = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='subnet.mask',
    )
    subnet_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='subnet.subnet_type.subnet_type',
    )
    class Meta:
        model = DeviceCircuitSubnets
        fields = ('circuit_name', 'subnet','subnet_mask','subnet_type')

class DeviceConn(QueryFieldsMixin, serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    poll_ip = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    mgmt_ip = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    bgp_as = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='site.bgp_as',
    )
    location = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='site.location',
    )
    site_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='site.site_type.site_type',
    )
    device_type = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
        source='model.device_type.device_type_plural',
    )
    circuit_subnets = CircuitSubnetsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Device   
        fields = ('site_id','poll_ip','mgmt_ip','bgp_as','hostname', 'device_type','location','site_type','circuit_subnets')
```

API output example

```
{
    "site_id": 50,
    "poll_ip": null,
    "mgmt_ip": "10.10.10.1",
    "bgp_as": "65001",
    "hostname": "STR-LDN-SW-02",
    "device_type": "Switches",
    "location": "Lonon",
    "site_type": "Showroom"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `DeviceConn` serializer, add a field to represent the relation you want to serialize:

```
class DeviceConn(serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField):
    your_related_field = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, 
    read_only=True, view_name=my_view)
    class Meta:
       fields = `__all__` # or add only the fields you want.
```

[See more here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedrelatedfield)

Comment: for some reason I cannot load the https://www.django-rest-framework.org website at the moment. im not sure a hyperlinked field is what Im after, I want a nested dictionary of circuit_subnets under the device, does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. That is the way to go. If you want more details, though, you may want to use CircuidSubnetsSerializer for the `your_related_field` as well.

Comment: would you happen to have a link to an example?

Comment: http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/relations

Look for `nested relationships`

Comment: ive updated the question with the nested relationship, however the api is still showing no data...

Comment: I needed to cast the Prefetch to match the name of the field in my serialiser Prefetch(
                                        'devicecircuitsubnets_set',
                                        queryset=DeviceCircuitSubnets.objects.all().select_related('subnet__subnet_type','subnet','circuit'),
                                        to_attr='circuit_subnets',
                                    )